# How to write formula criteria in SOQL?

Tags: soql, formula

I'm using a app from the app exchange and it requires the criteria for the field (rollup summary field) to be written in SOQL, and I have no idea how to write criteria that way. Can anyone help me? 
This is what I need the criteria to do, where "Month" and "Week" are the 2 fields, "Week" is a text formula and "Month" is a number formula. I need both to be true.

(Month = 8) AND (Week = "Week 5")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `API Names` of the fields in question. Assuming the `API Names` for your fields are `Month__c` and `Week__c`, your `SOQL` would be almost exactly what you have in your post, though parentheses are not necessary:

```
Month__c = 8 AND Week__c = "Week 5"
```

Note that you may need to switch from double quotes (`"`) to single quotes (`'`).